# Precisely designing activities for all screen sizes

Tags: android, screen-size

I know this question has been discussed a bunch, but I am curious about how to be extremely precise with app design so it looks the same on all screen sizes.

So, for example, right now I have a counter on my home screen that has text under each number saying the unit of the number. The `TextViews` are placed super precisely in the design layout in `Android Studio`, but of course with a new screen size the `TextViews` will shift according to the screen.

So in my `design view`, this is what the counter looks like.

[image]

But in my emulator, which just barely has different screen dimensions, the `TextViews` shift and it looks like this.

[image]

Even with the slight change in screen dimensions, the view is already being altered and does not look right.

I know that I can and design the screens individually for small screens, medium sized screens, large screens, and tablets, but I am wondering how I can precisely design things like this for all screen sizes so I do not have to make a separate design for every single screen size out there.

Like I said, I know this topic is discussed a lot, but I am just curious as to how precision can be accounted for, or if there is a better way for me to be positioning things inside my `.xml` files

Comment: Have you tried aligning the text views above the TextViews below it, instead of using a single TextView?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Are you saying change the timer into multiple `TextViews`? I think this may create more issues in the coding of the timer that I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: `I think this may create more issues in the coding of the timer` I don't think so, but good luck